# How to call SVN checkout in JMeter?

Tags: svn, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I need to checkout an XML file from SVN repository within JMeter test plan and parse the XML to search for a keyword. Has anyone had any success calling SVN check-in/check-out from JMeter script/test plan? Please share your code snippet/psedo code that would help to solve this challenge.

Background: I'm trying to validate an xml schema which is result of user interaction with application and checked-in to SVN repository. XML needs to be checked-out in oder to validate the schema. Using JMeter, i'm trying to automate these manual steps to save manual verification effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have SVN client installed on the host running JMeter you can use [OS Process Sampler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/javahl/)
2. If you don't have SVN client software installed and don't have possibility to install it, you can use Java client libraries like:

   - [Subversion Java Bindings](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/javahl/)
   - [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/)

   And i.e. [Beanshell Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to check your XML file out programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the help! I was able to implement using Beanshell.